# Combining 2 YouTube APIs?

Tags: javascript, api, video, youtube, youtube-api

I want to display the last video of a YouTube channel and use the data API to be able to change the background when I play the video.

But I don't understand so well the APIs yet and I succeeded in taking the last YouTube video from a channel (iframe API) AND using the data API for the background, but not together.

How to combine them?

Last video from a channel code:

```html
<iframe width="640" height="390" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed?max-results=1&controls=1&showinfo=0&listType=user_uploads&list=GoogleDevelopers" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Fiddle for changing the background with YouTube data API:

https://jsfiddle.net/LightBen/rjuph7jw/1/

Thanks =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use youtube API on existing iframe too, which means that you can display the iframe as in your question and **add** API functionality on it.

Like in this code:

```js
var tag = document.createElement('script');

tag.src = "//www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

var player;
window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function() {
  player = new YT.Player('player', {
    events: {
      'onReady': onPlayerReady,
      'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
    }
  });
}

function onPlayerReady(event) {
  event.target.playVideo();
}

function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
  switch(event.data) {
    case 1:
      $('body').addClass('play');
      break;
    case 2:
      $('body').removeClass('play');
  }
}
```

```css
body { 
  margin: 0; 
  transition: background-color 0.2s; 
}

.container { 
  width: 100%; 
  max-width: 1200px; 
  margin: 0 auto; 
  background-color: #eee; 
  padding: 10rem 3rem; 
  transition: background-color 0.2s; 
  text-align: center; 
}

body.play, .play .container { 
  background-color: #000; 
}

iframe { 
  margin: 0 auto; 
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.js"></script>
  <iframe id="player" width="640" height="390" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed?max-results=1&controls=1&showinfo=0&listType=user_uploads&list=GoogleDevelopers&enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

See it in action: http://output.jsbin.com/fologu